# Boot problem with hp probook 4310 laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, display

I have windows 7 and each time I reboot I can see only a black screen with a mouse. I thought maybe the laptop was in projector mode but even when I switch it back I still see the same thing.  I tried to connect it to a monitor to see if there is a response with no success.
Any one else encountered something similar?

Comment: Have you tried booting from a Linux live CD? Does the problem persist?

Answer (score 0):

I support two notebooks of this make and model.  I had to have the hard drive replaced on one and the other just loses power about once per week for no apparent reason.  I have not had the same problems you describe, but I have seen enough to know I would (will) not buy again.  I was profoundly disappointed.  I you can return this, I would.